# Finding the difference between a number variable within a repeating range?

Tags: php, math, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to process a numeric variable as follows-

if number is between 1-6 I want to count the difference between it and 7,
if number is between 15-20 I want to count the difference between it and 21,
if number is between 29-34 I want to count the difference between it and 35
and so on....

In other words, grouping it in multiples of 14, i need to find the difference between the first 6 numbers and the 7th number in each group.

I hope that makes sense.  i find it hard to explain in writing, my code isn't much better but i managed to get it to do what i want, but I know it isn't ideal so what I am looking for is a simpler solution to this.

```
$total = 'A NUMBER'; /* the input number (example: 16 )*/

    $fill =($total / 14);
    $fill = $fill - floor($fill);
    if($fill > 0 && $fill < 0.5) 
    {
        $fill = $total;
        while ($fill >= 7) 
        {
            $fill = ($fill - 7);
        }
        $fill = (7 - $fill);
    } else {
$fill=0;
}   

echo $fill; /* the output (example answer: 5) */
```

Comment: Why the `regex` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following function:

```
function MyProcess( $in ) {
    $quotient = (int) ($in / 7);
    if( ($quotient % 2 === 0) and ($in % 7 !== 0) )
        return 7 - ($in % 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works for the numbers 1-6 and 15-20 but when it's a number outside this range it returns $in rather than 0

Comment: unfortunately still giving wrong results for numbers 7 14 28 42, all should be displaying 0